# Setting a range from a cell to that cell's row value as the row index and the last column as the column index

Tags: excel, vba

trying to set a range from RValue to RValue row till last column in that row.
I have tried the code below but have been struggling to get any of them to work.

```
Range(RValue, Cells(RValue.Row, LastColumn.Column))
'or
Range(RValue, Cells(RValue.Row, LastColumn).Column)
'or
Range(RValue:cells(RValue,LastCol))
```

Comment: You need to provide some more context of the lines of code above, specifically, how `RValue` is derived and what type of variable it is.  It's hard to know how you're doing exactly.

Comment: You need to provide some more *context* here - as Skin points out we have no idea what type(s) of variables those are, or what values they might have, or what error(s) you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a compressed solution that can error when using on an empty row:

```
    Set r = Range(RValue, Cells(RValue.Row, Cells(RValue.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
    Debug.Print RValue.Address
```

And this is a more complex but robust solution:

```
    Dim RValue As Range, iCol As Long
    
    iCol = Cells(RValue.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - RValue.Column + 1
    If iCol < 1 Then iCol = 1
    Set RValue = RValue.Resize(1, iCol)
    Debug.Print RValue.Address
```